# How to check if a folder is the target of any junction points?

Tags: python, windows

Under Windows with Python 2.7 is there a way to check if a folder is the **target** of any junction points? And if so, find which symlink leads to it?

For example, in a `cmd` shell create a junction point using `mklink`.

```
C:\>mklink /J C:\junction C:\Users
Junction created for C:\junction <<===>> C:\Users
```

And in python (assuming no prior knowledge that this junction exists) test `"C:\Users"` if it is the target of any junction points, returning a list of symbolic links if `True`, in this case: `['C:\junction']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is hard to do efficiently, but you can scan for all existing junction points on a volume (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point "Obtaining a list of junction points").  You would then have to correlate those with what they actually point to.  A directory does not itself point back to existing junctions, so you are very limited in how you can find these.

Comment: Thanks @Wolf . I ended up doing what you suggested, do a single pass at building a library of existing junction points and targets to test against (using jaraco.windows.filesystem). It works but i would prefer a straight up filesystem query.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I put together using some of the code in an ActiveState recipe titled [*Windows directory walk using ctypes*](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578629-windows-directory-walk-using-ctypes/). There's probably a more direct way to do it than using the win32 `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` functions, but this seems to work in my limited testing.

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import Structure
from ctypes import byref
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
from ctypes import addressof

FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 16  # (0x10)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 1024  # (0x400)
MAX_PATH = 260

GetLastError = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError

class FILETIME(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dwLowDateTime", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwHighDateTime", wintypes.DWORD)]

class WIN32_FIND_DATAW(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dwFileAttributes", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("ftCreationTime", FILETIME),
                ("ftLastAccessTime", FILETIME),
                ("ftLastWriteTime", FILETIME),
                ("nFileSizeHigh", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("nFileSizeLow", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwReserved0", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwReserved1", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("cFileName", wintypes.WCHAR * MAX_PATH),
                ("cAlternateFileName", wintypes.WCHAR * 20)]

def find_junctions(folder):
    """ Return a list of subdirectories in folder which are junction points """
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        return False
    folder = unicode(folder)
    if not folder.startswith(u'\\\\?\\'):
        if folder.startswith(u'\\\\'):
            # network drive
            folder = u'\\\\?\\UNC' + folder[1:]
        else:
            # local drive
            folder = u'\\\\?\\' + folder

    junction_points = []
    data = WIN32_FIND_DATAW()
    h = ctypes.windll.kernel32.FindFirstFileW(os.path.join(folder, u'*'),
                                              byref(data))
    last_error = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
    if h < 0:
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.FindClose(h)
        if not sys.stderr.isatty():
            print >> sys.stderr, ('Failed to find first file %s' %
                                   os.path.join(folder, u'*'))
        if last_error != 5:  # access denied.
            raise WindowsError('FindFirstFileW %s, Error: %d' %
                               (folder, ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()))
        return []

    if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and
        data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT):
        if data.cFileName not in (u'.', u'..'):
            junction_points.append(data.cFileName[:])

    try:
        while ctypes.windll.kernel32.FindNextFileW(h, byref(data)):
            if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and
                data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT):
                if data.cFileName not in (u'.', u'..'):
                    junction_points.append(data.cFileName[:])
    except WindowsError as e:
        if not sys.stderr.isatty():
            print >> sys.stderr, (
                'Failed to find next file %s, handle %d, buff addr: 0x%x' %
                (os.path.join(folder, u'*'), h, addressof(data)))

    ctypes.windll.kernel32.FindClose(h)
    return junction_points

def is_junction_point(folder):
    dirpath, folder = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(folder))
    return unicode(folder) in find_junctions(dirpath)
```

Comment: good to know how to use ctypes to check for junction points. I ended up using [jaraco.windows](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaraco.windows) to get this information. I used it to build a list of existing junction points i can then use to test targets against. It's not great but it works. I just wish there was a way to directly query the file system for this and not have to do my current two pass method.